# MS Word 2013 Form, create a Save as and Submit Button with macro

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word, save-as

I have a simple form (from a template) in Word 2013 and have a 'Submit' button that will:
1. Gather information from fields in the document, name the document, and saveAs.
2. Email the form to pre-set email addresses.

Multiple people will open a document from the template

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document
Dim strTagNum As String, strNTID As String, strDate As String

strTagNum = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TagNum")(1).Range.Text
strNTID = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("NTID")(1).Range.Text
strDate = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date")(1).Range.Text
Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = strTagNum & "_" & strNTID & "_" & Format(strDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".docx"
StrPath = "V:\OPS\Central\Shared\ARM\ALERT"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument

Doc.SaveAs2 strFilename


With EmailItem
.Subject = "CGF ARM - ALERT ADD/DROP/CHANGE"
.Body = "Please Review this Alert for Continuous Improvement"
.To = "john.doe@example.com"
.Importance = olImportanceNormal
.Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
.Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Alert Record Submitted"

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

(Credit to Neil Malek at knacktraining.com)
and this topic
[Microsoft Word 2013 macro save file name from form content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047917/microsoft-word-2013-macro-save-file-name-from-form-content?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My questions are:
1. How do I specify the filepath for the saveAs?  I have the code in the Macro but the document is being saved in the individual users' Documents folder.

2. How to I tell the Macro to pull the username from the form and send it to "username"@example.com?

The rest of the macro works, when the 'Submit' button is pushed, the document is renamed, saved, and sent as an email to pre-set email addresses.

I've updated this from the original question, I was able to answer some of my prevous questions through trial and error.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you don't want to save as template? then what type file you want to SaveAs?

Comment: The template will be central, with many users opening a Document1.docx from it.  I'd like the Document1.docx to be saved as in a specific location with a filename taken from the form.

Comment: You need to Save it including the path: `Doc.SaveAs2 StrPath & "\" & strFilename`. Better to check if folder *StrPath* exists beforehand. Also consider a few UNC paths instead of `V:` like `\\FileServerNAS\Documents\ ` or `\\YourWorkDomain.com\DFSroot\Site\Documents\ `. Alternatively, add *CustomDocumentProperties* to store this path.

Comment: That worked for including the path, thanks!  I'd love to use a UNC path but for this application the company isn't set up that way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dig some more and solve the last part of my issue, thanks to this helpful link:

[excel: reference cell value to get email recipient for selected row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242301/excel-reference-cell-value-to-get-email-recipient-for-selected-row)

I ended up referencing the field value appended with & "example.com" and then .CC the string, worked like a charm!

Here's the code in total, I'm a very shallow end vba user so I'm sure there are cleaner ways, but this seems to work for what I need.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document
Dim strTagNum As String, strNTID As String, strDate As String

strTagNum = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TagNum")(1).Range.Text
strNTID = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("NTID")(1).Range.Text
strDate = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date")(1).Range.Text
Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = strTagNum & "_" & strNTID & "_" & Format(strDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".docx"
Email_Send_To = strNTID & "@example.com"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument

Doc.SaveAs2 StrPath & "V:\Central\Shared\ARM\ALERT\SubmittedForms\" & strFilename


With EmailItem
.Subject = "Continuous Improvement"
.Body = "Please Review this Alert for Continuous Improvement"
.To = "john.doe@example.com; onsiteengr@example.com; chrip@example.com"
.CC = Email_Send_To
.Importance = olImportanceNormal
.Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
.Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Alert Record Submitted"

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thanks to everyone who took a look and for the helpful code and comments!